# Can we create a Solr core with a JSON config?

Tags: python, json, solr

I am writing a function, which creates a new Solr core.

To create a core, you need to post data like (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=path_to_instance_directory&config=config_file_name.xml&schema=schem_file_name.xml&dataDir=data
```

But in this example, you need to refer to an **existing** config and schema.

In my app, each core can have a **different** configuration, so the best way will be to post the config and schema with JSON format to the server with a create request.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as far as I know, this is not possible at the moment (without creating the files on the server, then creating a core from the files).

You might want to use a more schemaless-ish structure for your schema if you need this kind of functionality, where you rather define a set of field pre/postfixes that map to different default settings for fields, and then use wildcard names to avoid having to define each field in your Schema.

A truly schema less alternative based on Lucene could be Elastic Search as well.